# Bot Framework Skype channel regular expressions not working

Tags: node.js, regex, botframework, skype

I built a bot using Bot Framework (node.js) with four connected channels (Messenger, Telegram, Skype and Web). At any moment the bot validates an inputted email address using a regular expression like this below:

```
/^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i
```

It is working properly on all channels, except the Skype. E.g: *gcfabri@gmail.com* match with this regex but on Skype channel it doesn't happens.

Comment: Check how the email is arriving to the bot

Answer (score 0):

According to GitHub user [nwhitmont](https://github.com/nwhitmont) (Stack Overflow [@nilsw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5199616/nilsw)) on issue [[Skype] Regular expression not working to find email address in chat message? #4024](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4024):

> Skype wraps email addresses in HTML tags, so you would need to adjust your RegEx accordingly.
>
> On Skype channel you need to check for:
>
> `<a href="mailto:name@email.com">name@email.com</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and resolved by using the following regular expression.

```
@"\b(?!mailto:)([\w-]+(.[\w-]+)@([a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)?.[a-z]{2,6}|(\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?)"
```

Skype is converting the user input email address to a HTML text e.g (`<a href='mailto:someone@example.com'>someemail@mail.com</a>`). We need to find out the email from this.

For more detail, please refer.
[Regex for detecting emails in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910514/regex-for-detecting-emails-in-text)